# Pass object with changed property

Tags: javascript

There is a function that requires and setting object.

```
var opt = {
    height: 300,
    maxLength: 4000,
    valueChangeEvent: "change",
    placeholder: "",
}
$(selector1).doStuff(opt);
$(selector2).doStuff(opt);
$(selector3).doStuff(opt);
$(selector4).doStuff(opt);
```

The thing is that the *placeholder* should be different every time. Currently, I create this opt object with every call but it seems ugly. Is there a way to pass this opt object while just changing one property?

Comment: I am confused. What are you trying to do? "The thing is that placeholder should be different every time" ==> What kind of values should it be?

Comment: What is the actual function you wish to call? (the real value of `doStuff`, that'll indicate what sort of solutions are possible)

Comment: @CertainPerformance the function doesn't really matter. It's just about spread operator that I forgot about.

Comment: Spread *works*, but I have the strong feeling that it's possible to write even more DRY code, depending on the circumstances. Even with using spread, the code is still pretty repetitive.

Comment: @CertainPerformance probably true however doStuff method is just a devExtreeme control called dxTextArea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your `opt` object as a template like this

```
$(selector1).doStuff({...opt, placeholder: 'different every time' })
```

The `...` operator [destructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the original `opt` object, then any further other properties are added to the result, replacing anything that conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

Use the spread syntax like this:

```js
let opt = {
    height: 300,
    maxLength: 4000,
    valueChangeEvent: "change",
    placeholder: "",
}

console.log({...opt, placeholder: "foo"});
console.log({...opt, placeholder: "bar"});
```

Or `Object.assign` like this:

```js
let opt = {
    height: 300,
    maxLength: 4000,
    valueChangeEvent: "change",
    placeholder: "",
}

console.log(Object.assign({}, opt, { placeholder: "foo" }));
console.log(Object.assign({}, opt, { placeholder: "bar" }));
```

Both of these solutions are non-destructive (i.e. they don't change `opt`). If you want a destructive solution, leave out the first argument from `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function which produces `opt` for you. In this function, you can pass the placeholder as an argument to be used like so:

```js
const createOpt = (placeholder = '') => ({
    height: 300,
    maxLength: 4000,
    valueChangeEvent: "change",
    placeholder
});


console.log(createOpt("x"));
console.log(createOpt("y"));
console.log(createOpt());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used spread syntax, allows an iterate are expected in this case:

```
$(selector1).doStuff({...opt, placeholder: 'Everything' })
```

read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)